# Javascript - window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, closures

So I have this code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var x = 2;
});
console.log(x); // undefined
```

Is there anyway to make this code working without affecting the code inside the callback at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "have access to the window"? Sorry, what exactly do you want to do? You want to have access to x inside the callback?

Comment: @debeka No, I want to define x inside the callback so I then can access it outside.

Comment: Try:  var x;//outside  window.add..{.//define x here..}); console.log(x);

Comment: @debeka No, but I still want to be able to do var x inside

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want. Depends on it: If you just want to display x on the console, you can put console.log(x) inside the function. If you want to access x by other functions, it is other answer.

Comment: `x` *only* exists inside that anonymous function.  The only way to access it outside would be to modify that function.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you want to do something like this:

```js
var x;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    x = 2;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    alert(x);
});
```

There were several problems with your code:

1. You were declaring the variable `x` within the callback function. Hence, you couldn't access it from the global scope.
2. Even if you declared the variable `x` within the global scope and defined it within the callback function, `console.log` would still print `undefined` because when `console.log` is called, the value of `x` is not yet defined since the callback function was never called (at best, it would be called on the next iteration of the event loop).

The solution is to declare `x` in the global scope, define it within the first callback function of the `load` event and have the post-processing done in the second callback function of the `load` event. Nevertheless, this is a very bad solution. A better solution would be to move everything into the first callback function of the `load` event as follows:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var x = 2;
    alert(x);
});
```

Hope that helps.